# A quadrilateral ABCD satisfies the following relationship with respect to any point $M$ in the plane $AM^2+ CM^2 = BM^2 + DM^2$

Tags: geometry

This quadrilateral could be

1. A parallelogram
2. A rectangle
3. A square
4. A rhombus
5. None of the above

The answer can have multiple answers.

Please provide the proof of your answer. I would be grateful for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: First take $\;M=A\;$, then take $\;M=B\;$ ....what do you get??

Comment: i did not quite get you...

Comment: How can i put that..if i did how would i use the given equality?

Comment: Well, for one: $$M=A\implies 0^2+CA^2=BA^2+DA^2\implies$$ we have something here that can be a straight angle triangle...take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Option **3** and **2** are easy to prove to be right $\to$ option **5** is false.

Then, option **4** can be easily found false by setting $M \equiv A$ ($0+\overline{AC}^2=\overline{BA}^2+\overline{DA}^2 \to \overline{AC}^2=2\overline{BA}^2 \to$ rhombus needs to be a square).

At last, option **1** is false too by setting $M \equiv A$ ($0+\overline{AC}^2=\overline{BA}^2+\overline{DA}^2 \to \overline{AC}^2=2\overline{CD}^2 \to$ parallelogram needs to be a rectangle).

As for the first proof, see image below: [image]

We have $$\overline{AM}^2=x^2+y^2, \overline{BM}^2=(x-b)^2+y^2, \overline{CM}^2=(x-b)^2+(y-a)^2 \text{ and } \overline{DM}^2=x^2+(y-a)^2$$
thus $$\overline{AM}^2+\overline{CM}^2=x^2+y^2+(x-b)^2+(y-a)^2=(x-b)^2+y^2+x^2+(y-a)^2=\overline{BM}^2+\overline{DM}$$